# Vue transition: how to slide correctly?

Tags: vue.js, transition, slide

I have a `v-card` that I want to animate back and forth with one click.

If I click on an arrow to the left, the card should scroll to the right and then immediately scroll back in from the left. The other button should work the other way around.

The problem is, nothing happens here. What am I doing wrong?

**My template:**

```
<v-card>
    <v-btn icon @click="back = false">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-left</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon @click="back = true">
        <v-icon>mdi-arrow-right</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</v-card>

<transition :name="back ? 'slide-fade' : 'slide-fade-reverse'">
    <v-card max-width="200" class="mx-auto mt-5" height="80">
        <span class="d-flex justify-center pt-7">{{back}}</span>
    </v-card>
</transition>
```

**My script:**

```
data() {
    return {
        back: false,
    }
},
```

**My css:**

```
/* Prev */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-enter {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide-fade-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Next */
.slide-fade-reverse-enter-active {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-reverse-leave-active {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-reverse-enter {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.slide-fade-reverse-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

I made a Pen for this: https://codepen.io/Tenarius/pen/WNwdEve

Comment: You're expecting the same element to be two elements at once. During the transition, the `<v-card>` is expected to be both the exiting one and the entering one. It should be obvious you need two or more elements for it to work.

Comment: The `v-card` contains **date**-specific data. With each click, the data in this item is exchanged and a visualization with an animation should take place. There is only **one** `v-card`.

Comment: `leave` and `enter` transitions only apply when the DOM element is inserted into DOM and when removed. Your `<v-card>` is always there. If you have more than one card, please create a relevant [mcve].

Comment: If vue transitions are out of the question, do you know an alternative?

Comment: I don't see how they're out of the question. The only "tricky" part is you're actually dealing with a collection of one element. Think of it as a paginated list where the page contains only one item. But it's still a collection. Therefore, you should use the proper element, which is `transition-group`. See it [working here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/MWyrEgr).

Answer (score 1):

In order for `leave` and `enter` transition to work, the `<transition>` element has to have a `v-if` condition. When it changes from `false` to `true`, the element gets inserted into DOM and animates according to `enter` transition. When the condition changes from `true` to `false`, the leaving transition is performed and, when it ends, the element is removed from DOM.

However, you don't have such a condition. You're simply updating the cards contents and expect it to be removed from DOM and replaced by a new one.

In order to achieve the expected functionality you should use a list of cards (which would only contain the currently active card), coupled with using [`<transition-group>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) which, internally, uses the same mechanics as `transition` but the `v-if` condition is whether the element is part of the collection or not.

In your case, the "collection" would be a filtered list of cards, containing only one card. With this technique, the leaving element gets the leave animation, while the entering element gets the enter animation, as the elements are actually removed and added to DOM, according to changes in your model.

See it working [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/MWyrEgr).

Answer (score 0):

Since a transition needs leave and enter and thus the element has to "disappear" and "reappear", `setTimout` can be used to build a workaround.

```
data() {
    return {
        back: false,
        loading: false
    }
},
methods: {
    loadTimeout() {
        this.loading = true
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.loading = false
        }.bind(this), 500);
    }
}
```

The card can then be expanded with `v-show="!loading"` and the left- and right-buttons have to call the `loadTimeout()` function.

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/Tenarius/pen/WNwdEve)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this, and it is working:

```scss
// index.scss
$animation-duration: 0.15s;

.step-next-enter-active,
.step-next-leave-active,
.step-prev-enter-active,
.step-prev-leave-active {
  transition:
    transform #{$animation-duration} ease,
    opacity #{$animation-duration} ease;
}

.step-next-enter-from,
.step-prev-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(32px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.step-next-leave-to,
.step-prev-enter-from {
  transform: translateX(-32px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.step-next-leave-from,
.step-next-enter-to,
.step-prev-leave-from,
.step-prev-enter-to {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
...
const animationDirection = ref<"step-next" | "step-prev">("step-next");

// Calculate the height of the current step for smooth transition
const currentStepHeight = ref<number>();

watch(
  () => [store.currentStep],
  ([currentStep], [oldStep]) => {
    if (currentStep !== oldStep) {
      animationDirection.value =
        currentStep > oldStep ? "step-next" : "step-prev";
    }
  },
  {
    flush: "pre",
  }
);

// Get the current transitioning element height
function onEnter(e: Element): void {
  const elHeight = e.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  currentStepHeight.value = elHeight;
}
</script>

<template>
...
        <div
          class="overflow-hidden transition-all"
          :style="{
            height: currentStepHeight + 'px',
            maxHeight: currentStepHeight + 'px',
          }"
        >
          <Transition
            :name="animationDirection"
            mode="out-in"
            @enter="onEnter"
          >
            <Component :is="steps[store.currentStep - 1]" />
          </Transition>
        </div>
...
</template>
```

Hope it helps!